# How to Update 1 record and auto update for other records in same table using Access 2010

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I just create simple table in access 2010. 
table name is Sheet1. 
Columns:

```
ID, BarcodeNo, NoParticipant, GiftAlreadyTaken
1 , 80001    , ANDREW       , No
2 , 80002    , ANDREW       , No
3 , 80003    , ANDREW       , No
4 , 80004    , MATHEW       , No
5 , 80005    , MATHEW       , No
6 , 80006    , RICHARD       , No
```

Example
ANDREW give a barcode number is 80002 and We're input and save and update all Andrew barcode (80001, 80002, 80003) so If one of the barcode that has been scanned, it will immediately update all. So GiftAlreadyTaken with participant is Andrew change to Yes

How should I do, if I'm using access 2010?

Comment: I am afraid your question isn't very clear. You might like to try and tidy up the table example in order for people to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA, which I assume what you are using based on your tag you can perform the following update query or use the structure to create something similar. I don't fully understand your question so it might not be exact.

```
Currentdb.Execute "UPDATE Sheet1 " _ 
    & "SET GiftAlreadyTaken = 'Yes' " _ 
    & "WHERE NoParticipant = 'Andrew';"
```

Comment: Sorry about my question.

Comment: I means
I scan barcode in field barcodeno like as 80001 and shown in object textbox participant is ANDREW and also GiftAlreadyTaken is No (False) - Checklist.
And I checklist this to TRUE (YES) and is auto to update all in barcodeno with ANDREW (80001, 80002 and 80003)